# jquery countdown timer within a php loop

Tags: php, jquery

i want to use keith woods countdown timer jquery plugin (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to show the time left to bid on an auction but im having trouble with it.

when a user searches, php retrieves multiple search results, with a timestamp for the endtime stored as a varchar.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $numrows++;
        $ID = $row['ID'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $owner = $row['owner'];
        $cprice = $row['cprice'];
        $iprice = $row['iprice'];
        $incprice = $row['incprice'];
        $etime = $row['etime'];
        $nextBid = $cprice + $incprice;

$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username");
$stmt2->bindParam(":username", $owner,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->execute();

$thisuser = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$location = $thisuser['location'];

        echo'
        <tr class="resultindex">

        <td class="imgCol"><a href="displayAuct.php?id='.$ID.'"><img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$name.'" /></a></td>
        <td class="infoCol">

            <div class="nameDiv">
                <a class="nameLink" href="displayAuct.php?id='.$ID.'">'.$name.'</a><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="descDiv">
                <span class="priceLabel2">'.$desc.'</span>
            </div>

            <div class="userdiv">
                <span class="fromuser">Location: </span><br/>
                <span class="location">'.$location.'</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; background-color:#330066;" ></td>
        <td class="priceCol">
            <div class="currentp"><span class="priceLabel">Current Bid: </span><br/><span class="price1">$'.$cprice.'</span></div>
            <div class="instantp"><span class="priceLabel2">Instant Sale: </span><br/><span class="price2">$'.$iprice.'</span></div>
            <div style="height:5px;"></div>
            <div class="incp"><span class="priceLabel2">Next Bid:</span><br/><span class="price2">$'.$nextBid.'</span></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; background-color:#330066;"></td>
        <td class="timerCol">
            <div id="timeRow">
                <span class="timeleft">Time Left: </span>
            </div>
            <div id="countdownRow"></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
```

at the bottom of the code, i want the countdown timer based on that particular item to be displayed in the countdownRow div.

i dont know how to handle this with javascript, ive come up with:

```
var timestamp = <?php echo $etime; ?> * 1000;
    var endTime = new Date();
    endTime.setTime(timestamp);


    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $(".cdtimer").load(function(){
            $(".cdtimer").countdown({until: endTime});
        });
    });
```

but this doesnt seem to work. Anyone got an idea of what i need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

first remark: id attributes in html must be unique. so every row needs a unique id.

add the `$etime` for each row into a seperate div to have all the endtimes available in the html.

use jquery to find all `timerCol` columns and start a new timer for each result.

```
$(".timerCol .timeLeft").each(function() {
    endtime = $(this).find(".timeRowValue").val();
    $(this).countdown({until: endTime});
};
```